# Flex Fullscreen Problems

Tags: apache-flex, stagedisplaystate

I'm having problems with Full Screen in Flex.

Here's the Code:

```
private function toggleFullScreen(event:Event):void {
            try {
                 switch (Application.application.stage.displayState) {
                    case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN:
                        // If already in full screen mode, switch to normal mode. 
                        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        //If not in full screen mode, switch to full screen mode.
                        Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
                        break; 
                }
            } catch (err:SecurityError) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
```

I've already verified that this method is correctly being called, and that the SWITCH/CASE is working.

Still, after setting the displayState, nothing happens, and the attribute displayState remais with "normal" String.

I tested with previous versions of Firefox and Internet Explorer, but it didn't work either.

Does anybody know why is this happening? I'm new in flex and this code was developed by previous developers, that aren't working here anymore.

I've been searching a fix for weeks, but I didn't find anything that could help.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to include the "allowFullscreen" in both of your param tag and embed attribute within the HTML template:

```
<object> 
    ... 
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
    <embed ... allowfullscreen="true" /> 
</object>
```

And just a reference to the stage should be enough:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Comment: Philarmon, thank you for the answer! These atributes were already set. I changed the reference, but still not working. :(